# How to access callback arguments within another function?

Tags: javascript, function, callback, arguments

I am trying to capture the arguments that are being passed to callback 'func' function. However, when I try to console log arguments inside my 'cache' function it doesn't give anything except the name of the callback function.

But when I add a secondary inner function, the logging works just fine and it lets me access the arguments received by the callback. I really want to understand how inner function can perform the task, but the outer function cannot.

```
function cache(func) {
  console.log(arguments); //logs { '0': [Function: complexFunction] }

  return function () {
  console.log(arguments); //logs { '0': 'foo', '1': 'bar' }
  }
}

var complexFunction = function(arg1, arg2) { return arg1 + arg2 };
var cachedFunction = cache(complexFunction);

console.log(cachedFunction('foo', 'bar')); // complex function should be executed
```

Comment: `arguments` refers to the arguments object of the *current* function. So save it to another variable and use it instead.

Comment: *"how inner function can perform the task, but the outer function cannot"* How should this even be possible? When you call the inner function, the outer function already terminated. `'foo'` and `'bar'` are passed to the *inner* function. There is no way for the outer function to access those since it isn't even running at that moment. Maybe I'm misunderstanding the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inner function is a different function. When you call it (because it has been returned and assigned to `cachedFunction`), you pass it different arguments.

```
cachedFunction('foo', 'bar')
```

> complex function should be executed

It isn't.

You never execute `complexFunction`.

You pass it as an argument to `cache`, and `cache` passes it (written in the `arguments` object) to `console.log`, but it *never* gets called.

If you want to call it, then you need to actually do that.

```
function cache(func) {
  console.log(arguments); //logs { '0': [Function: complexFunction] }

  return function () {
  console.log(func.apply(null, arguments));
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! And sorry, I forgot to remove the comment about execution. I am really interested in where the inner function gets its arguments from.

I especially like what you wrote here:

"The inner function is a different function. When you call it (because it has been returned and assigned to cachedFunction), you pass it different arguments."

Could you please elaborate a bit more?

Comment: @dsvorc41: You are calling the inner function here: `cachedFunction('foo', 'bar')`. Hence it gets the arguments `'foo'` and `'bar'`.

Comment: @dsvorc41 — I quoted the bit of code which passes arguments to the inner function immediately after I said "you pass it different arguments"